# How to pass arguments to the chained promises callbacks

Tags: javascript, promise, q

How can i pass arguments to Sequence promises using q.promises

```
var argumentsArray = ["PARAM1", "PARAM2", "PARAM3"]
var arr = [];
function aJaxCall(argumentsArray) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        /*
            Here i want to get the passed parameter and use it
            in my post request
        */
        url: 'someurl.com' + PARAMS,
        // data: data,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            arr.push(data);
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

var result = Q();   
for (var i = 0, len = argumentsArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    /* Pass the argumentsArray[i]
        for each then call, i want to be able to pass
        the current argumentsArray value
    */
    result = result.then(aJaxCall);
}
```

So far i tried with properties to the aJaxCall function itself and
then handle it with arguments.calee.prop

```
for (var i = 0, len = argumentsArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    aJaxCall.prop = argumentsArray[i];
    result = result.then(aJaxCall);
}
```

and then within the aJaxCall function i tried to get the parameters like this:

```
arguments.callee.prop
```

but it is always binding the last element in the argumentsArray, cause the for loop finish and the .then is fired later in the cycle. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `arguments`, never use `callee`

Comment: Don't create a custom `deferred` (where you have forgotten error handling)! Just assimilate the jqXHR promise that jQuery gives you: `return Q($.ajax(…));`

Comment: i know that callee is depricated, but i couldn't come up with something that works, so i pretty much tried all i can think of

Comment: cane you give me some code example of this approach

Comment: You need to use a closure to store the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method that returns an anonymous function that calls ajaxCall with the passed parameters:

```
var callWithArgs = function(arg) {
  return function () {
     return ajaxCall(arg);
  }
}

for (var i = 0, len = argumentsArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    result = result.then(callWithArgs(argumentsArray[i]));
}
```

Comment: this is not working, since .then expects a function that return promise

Comment: Easy fix. Just added a return ajaxCall.

Comment: tried this already - the ajax are not called at all

Comment: my bad, this is actaully working...

Comment: OK, sounds good. Also, looking at the Q documentation, I don't see a use case for "var q = Q(); q = q.then(...);". Are you sure it's doing what you want?

Comment: yes, that is what im after. you can see the var q = Q() in the here
http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#tutorial/sequences